# Enable GD Jpeg Support on Docker

Tags: php, docker, libjpeg

I trying to build my PHP project with docker, and need to install GD, libpng and libjpeg libraries. I get success in installation of GD and libpng, but the **libjpeg** does not appear activated for me.

After construct the image with Docker, I get this data of GD in PHP info:

[image]

I tried install with docker 7.4, but the problem persists, and my code for installation of GD in Dockerfile is that:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

This is the code recommended in the docker documentation, but if someone can help me with some change, I thank.

Comment: Does [comment in this issue](https://gist.github.com/shov/f34541feae29afedd93208df4bf428f3?permalink_comment_id=3628529#gistcomment-3628529) work for you? He use `--with-jpeg` instead (for PHP 7.4 - I hope you are using this version) and this also [documented on PHP website](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php).

Comment: Yes, at the first time of I follow this instructions don't worked, but after a few modifications in my dockerfile it worked. Thank you for help!

Comment: @IandellLorenzon can you please share what dockerfile modifications you made? I'm having similar issues. Thanks

Comment: @rjbathgate remove these `--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ ` and just use `--with-freetype` and `--with-jpeg` like above comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/18705923/iandell-lorenzon could you share your dockerfile changes as an answer?